# SEO - moving a regional optimated site (city name in URL) to another city

Tags: seo

A SEO optimized website does already exist, but that website is optimizied to a specific city (city A) and has the city name in the URL also the business is moving from that city to another city now (city B)

What is the best way to handle that situation regarding SEO? I thought about using a new URL, without any city name in it and redirecting the old URL to that URL. Implementing a new site in the website informing about the new business in city B in order to built up the seo for the new city.

Do you think this is a good way to handle that? Are there any other alternatives? Are there any risks? Will the ranking for the first URL drop or get lost?

Answer (score 1):

The best optimize way of doing that is - 
If you are doing it with the same domain then put the city name B in URL and do 301 redirect from Page A to page B.

By doing the same you preserve the PA & DA both for your new URL.

While if you are going with different domain for your new site then you could go as you explained.

Comment: what would be the better way to do it - 1) keeping all website data on the same webspace in the folder of the old domain and redirecting to the new domain or
2) moving all website data on the webspace to the new domain and redirecting the old domain to the new one? Or in short words: do I have to move the websitecontent to the new domain in order to get a better seo result?